# Max size of an Android Application

Tags: android, google-play

What is the maximum size for an Android Application that can be uploaded for Google Play? Is there some official resource or documentation for this? For example I see some games that are in GBs so is there an upward limit?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536463/android-application-apk-maximum-size

Comment: Not relevant I am asking about google play limit while deploying an app. But thnx for the reply.

Comment: I see, then it's 50MB (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en) and you can add extensions

Comment: @RamGAthreya And what is the size of a debug app?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Android Market raises maximum app size to 4GB, APK files still limited to 50MB

Please study these links, you will get your answer:

[Android APK size limitation in Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371302/android-apk-size-limitation-in-google-play)

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

http://www.engadget.com/2012/03/05/android-market-4gb-app-limit/

### Update (28 Sep 2015)

The Google Play team (ANDROID DEVELOPER BLOG) ::(GOOGLE) update the max size limit. They are increasing the APK file size limit to **100MB** from **50MB**. This means developers can publish APKs up to 100MB in size,Please refer this link for more information on [Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/09/support-for-100mb-apks-on-google-play.html?linkId=17389452)

Comment: What is the difference between Android Market app size and APK Size? As I can see there are few apps of size in GBs.

Answer (score 9):

**Update (As of Sep 28, 2015):**

> APK files have a maximum file size, based on the Android version that your APK supports: If you can't support all devices with a single APK, you can [upload multiple APKs](https://d.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks) using the same app listing that target different device configurations.
>
> - **100 MB** – APKs that target Android 2.3 and higher (API level 9-10 and 14+)
> - **50 MB** – APKs that target Android 2.2 and lower (API level 8 or lower)
>
> **Tip:** Users must run Play Store version 5.2 or higher to install 100 MB APKs.

[Reference](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#size) to Play Console Help.

---

**Old Answer:**

See [here for details](https://d.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/launch-checklist)

> Currently, the maximum size for an APK published on Google Play is 50 MB.
>
> You can use up to two (2) APK Expansion Files, each up to 2 GB in size, for each APK.

Answer (score 7):

Google Play is increasing the APK file size limit to 100MB from 50MB.

Answer (score 2):

[Answer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en)

Summary:

**apk:** 50MB

**expansion files:** 2GB

Comment: you did not read the answer you link to: `Google will store two expansion files per application. Each which can be up to 2GB in size.` so expansion file**s**: 4GB (2*2GB)

Comment: Google Play answer has been updated and your answer now contains an outdated data.

Answer (score 1):

All this being said, your apk size has that 100mb limit but your obb can be huge. ie a typical unreal delivery will have a 50mb apk and 100-300 obb and its accepted. I believe the obb can reach 2-4gb as long as you use sdk level-26.

Answer (score 0):

APK file: maximum supported size for a single APK is 50MB.

[Upload applications to Play Store](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload apk to play store upto **100 MB**. And then manage other big data with .obb files.

You can maintain the big data in .obb file in two different packs

1 - Main extention file i.e "main.version_name.package_name.obb" : upto **2 GB**
2 - Patch extention file i.e "patch.version_name.package_name.obb" : upto **2 GB**

For Example:
main.1.com.myapp.com.obb
patch.1.com.myapp.com.obb

obb file always stored in Android/obb/<your_package>/